# Disabling Anonymous authentication for web application causes error

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, authentication, iis-7

I am trying to enable Windows authentication and disable anonymous authentication for an intranet application.  I have already enabled Windows authentication and disabled anonymous in IIS7, and set my Web.Config to use Windows authentication.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

When I deploy and run my application, only the page header will load.  When I navigate to my Service.svc file in Chrome or IE, I get the following error:

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.
>
> System.NotSupportedException: Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

I would assume that this is a problem with my Web.Config or Service.svc.cs, but I cannot identify it.  This only happens for one service.  Enabling Anonymous authentication in IIS7 will resolve the issue, but I need it disabled.

In my ServiceRefernces.ClientConfig, I have:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
  <endpoint address="http://OHARA-WIN7/nightlyweb/Service.svc"       
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"    
      contract="ServiceReference2.IService"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have seen a lot of posts where people were told to set TransportClientCredentialType to Ntlm, but VisualStudio does not recognize this element.

Comment: Its not likely to be service related, but it's easy to tell; Does it happen for every service on your site or just one service?

Comment: im abit guessing (and therefor not posting this as an answer), but maybe it has something to do with the authentication settings of iis? did you marked windows authentication there as well? EDIT: what i said might be true if you dont work in integrated mode, leavnig separate authentication processing both in iis and asp.net

Comment: In IIS?  Yes.  I already specified this in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  After further comparison with one of my manager's projects, I noticed that I was supposed to add this code to my Web.COnfig, and NOT my ServiceReferences.ClientConfig like I thought I needed to.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding>
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```